# Missing "mime.types" file causing nginx to fail

Tags: arch-linux, nginx

I'm on Arch Linux and installed `nginx-mainline`. I get an error when running `sudo systemctl start`. Here's the output of `sudo systemctl status nginx.service`:

```
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-08-22 21:04:55 EDT; 8s ago
    Process: 2660 ExecStart=/usr/bin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid; error_log stderr; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 22 21:04:55 archlinux.homelab.local systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Aug 22 21:04:55 archlinux.homelab.local nginx[2660]: 2020/08/22 21:04:55 [emerg] 2660#2660: open() "/etc/nginx/mime.types" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:18
Aug 22 21:04:55 archlinux.homelab.local systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 22 21:04:55 archlinux.homelab.local systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 22 21:04:55 archlinux.homelab.local systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

My `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file includes this:

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    # Bunch of other code I've excluded for simplicity
}
```

And it's true, there's not `mime.types` file in `/etc/nginx/`. How do I get `nginx` working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dunno about arch-linux, but normally the package should include the file.

However, you can always get a replacement from upstream :-)

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nginx/nginx/master/conf/mime.types

That contains the current master `mime.types` file.

You can just download that file and put it in the configuration directory.

Comment: The [PKGBUILD removes the file](https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-packages/blob/packages/nginx/trunk/PKGBUILD#L120) and says it is in the mailcap package. Reinstalling mailcap creates the file.

Comment: @spelufo This comment worked like a charm. `sudo pacman -Sy mailcap`